# Can someone help me, I am not sure why the font I used in my website is different from the one I am referencing

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hi I want to have a similar font as this website, but I inspected the website, and cannot replicate the font that was used in the website that I am creating.

The website: https://zyro.com/preview/niko

[font preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvHTX.png).

Here is my code:

```css
body {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.intro {
    font-family: "Cormorant Garamond", serif;
    font-size: 54px;
}

.emphasise {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: "Cormorant Garamond light", serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Jonathan Ngien</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
            <!--Toggler/Collapsible button-->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#targetnavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!--Navbar links-->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="targetnavbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/jon.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/education.html">EDUCATION</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/aboutme.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="/contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="container">
            <h1 class="display-3">
                <span class="intro">
                    HI, MY NAME IS
                    <span class="emphasise">Jonathan.</span>
                    I'M CURRENTLY A STUDENT IN THE
                    <span class="emphasise">National University of Singapore.</span>
                </span>
            </h1>
        </main>
    </body>

</html>
```

After I inspected the page, all i managed to find was the font Cormorant Garamond, but after adding that form to my CSS file, the font that i got was thicker than the one in the website, as seen in this [my website's font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PhO6.png). I can tell the new font is applied but it is much thicker than the one I referenced to.

So, I tried changing the thickness of the form using font-weight, but it doesn't change.

Can someone tell me if I am doing something wrong, or is there another way to make the font thinner?

Comment: please  attach some relevant ccs code + html configuration. we can't tell what went wrong base on thin-air. thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) How did you inspect and find Cormorant Garamond? I don't see that font. 2) You could at least make sure the links you paste work 3) Don't post pictures, post code ([mcve]).

Comment: Alright, i made the necessary changes

Comment: Where do you load the Cormorant Garamond font?

Comment: If I use the right font, the right font-size, the right font weight and the right color, I get the same output.

Comment: I loaded it in CSS, style sheet - could you load your output because i cant get it

Answer (score -2):

So it looks like you need to add this font from google fonts to your html head.

you can get the fonts from here: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cormorant+Garamond

And here's a working example using the font weight of 300 like in the website you provided:

```css
body {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.intro {
    font-family: "Cormorant Garamond", serif;
    font-size: 54px;
}

.emphasise {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: "Cormorant Garamond", serif;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com"><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin><link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cormorant+Garamond:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>



<span class="intro">
                    HI, MY NAME IS
                    <span class="emphasise">Jonathan.</span>
                    I'M CURRENTLY A STUDENT IN THE
                    <span class="emphasise">National University of Singapore.</span>
                </span>
```

Comment: 1) There is not *Cormorant Garamond light* font 2) You are not loading the italic version of the font 3) The demo website uses 700 as the bold font weight (not 800 as before your edit, not 500 as after your edit) 4) Now you edited your answer and fixed these previous points but why do you load all these unnecessary font weights? 5) The output of your code snippet still doesn't look the same as the demo website.

Comment: Its an example for the OP to see.  I loaded all the fonts so he can play around with it.  The core of my answer is that he needed to add the appropriate font and sizes via google fonts to the head of his html.  On his example website they do use 300 font weight, and sure ok ill go ahead and make it 700 then in the example as is the heavier font.

Comment: Fine, but then mention it in your answer otherwise it might not be clear for OP.

Comment: If I write "Niko" instead of "Jonathan" I don't see the same output (visually) than on the example website. Could you find out why?

Comment: @MrUpsidown, yes i notice that it not the same output why is that so?